# How to insert some line(Three lines) after one line(where string matched) in XML file which I opened in notepad++

Tags: xml, notepad++

I want to add below line(s):

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````
 <ON STMT="*" CODE="COMPSTAT LE 4">
     <DOACTION ACTION="OK" />
  </ON>
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````
===============================================================================
After the below string line whenever there will be any match I want to add the above contain. Need to insert new contain in "need to add here"

<ON STMT="*" CODE="NOTOK">
    <DOSHOUT URGENCY="R" MESSAGE="CTLM Job %%JOBNAME.(%%ORDERID.), has failed @" DEST="SNOW" />
</ON>
"Need to add here"
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````

===========================================================================

Answer (score 1):

You could add lines after the match string by using the `Replace` function to replace it with a new string that starts with the matched string.

In the `Replace` panel, enter the following having `Regular expression` enabled:

```
Find what: ("Whatever pattern you want to match")
Replace what: $1\n<ON STMT="*" CODE="COMPSTAT LE 4">\n\t<DOACTION ACTION="OK" />\n</ON>
```

Using regular expression, you are able to capture the matched string with parentheses and add it as a part of the replaced string.

Comment: It is not about replacing, it is about, need to add lines after string matched line.

Comment: @SourinBiswas: Have you tried this solution? It works fine, I think you didn't understand. It replaces existing lines by themselves + new lines.